# Populating an excel sheet with items from a list box?

Tags: excel, vba

Tried using this coding but no luck:

```
MsExcel.Range("B2").Value = List5.List(0)

MsExcel.Range("c2").Value = List5.List(1)
```

my list box name is listbox5. Thank you for any help you can provide

**Edit by belisarius**

*Just adding text from the author's comment*

here is the code I am trying to use it with:

```
Private Sub mdofficecommandbutton_Click() 
   Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\o075535\Desktop\Workstation- printer setup\Workstation blank template.xls" 
   Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 6) = txtdepartment.Text 
   Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 7) = 17012 
   Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 8) = txtprinter.Text 
   Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 7) = 17004 
   Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 8) = txtprinter.Text 
   MsExcel.Range("B2").Value = List5.List(0) 
   MsExcel.Range("c2").Value = List5.List(1) 
End Sub
```

Comment: here is the code I am trying to use it with:

Comment: Private Sub mdofficecommandbutton_Click()
  
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\o075535\Desktop\Workstation- printer setup\Workstation blank template.xls"

Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 6) = txtdepartment.Text

Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 7) = 17012

Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 8) = txtprinter.Text

Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 7) = 17004

Sheets("LWS NEW BUILD").Cells(3, 8) = txtprinter.Text
MsExcel.Range("B2").Value = List5.List(0)

MsExcel.Range("c2").Value = List5.List(1)

End Sub

Comment: Shouldn't "List5" be "listbox5"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
Sheet3.Range("E4").Value = Sheet3.ListObjects(1).ListRows(3).Range(1, 2).Value
```

It takes the 1st list, 3rd row, 2nd column value and places it into "E4". You reference the list with the ListObjects member.

Here is how to copy many values from a list into the worksheet

```
Dim n As Integer
n = Sheet3.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count

Sheet3.Range("E5").Resize(n, 1).Value = _
  Sheet3.ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range(1, 2).Resize(n, 1).Value
```

the variable `n` holds the number to copy (here n=#rows) and then use the 2nd column (with Range(1,2)) with n-th rows.